# Undefined, a la hora de acceder a los valores de un token

Tags: typescript, jsonwebtoken

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio para aprender a usar Tokens. El token se genera perfectamente, pero cuando intento acceder a la funcion de logearme con ese usuario, me pierde los datos en una parte de la funciona verificar token.
Estoy usando Typescript, tengo el mismo ejercicio hecho con JS y me funciona perfectamente, creo que puedo estar cometiendo un error a la hora de construir la interface Payload.

Aqui os dejo mi codigo de la funcion en donde esta el error:

```
export const verifyToken = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {

    const token = req.header('auth-token');

    if(!token) {
        return res.status(401).json({
            msg: 'Acceso denegado'
        });
    };

    const payload = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET || 'secret_token') as IPayload;
    console.log(payload)
    req.userId = payload._id;
    console.log(payload._id)

    next();
    
};
```

Como veis tengo un console.log(payload), donde ahí si que todavía estoy recibiendo toda la data,os dejo aqui mismo el resultado en consola. Le he quitado numeros al token, por si alguien se da cuenta.

```
 {
[1]   data: {
[1]     role: 'USER',
[1]     status: true,
[1]     _id: '60312e74daed1017c89d3035',
[1]     name: 'gggg',
[1]     surname: 'gggg',
[1]     age: 3,
[1]     email: 'd@d',
[1]     password: '$2b$10$arF.tnr7KSgWgHpvdS7FmOZ84l6.tXONVtte0',
[1]     date: '2021-02-20T15:44:52.384Z',
[1]     __v: 0
[1]   },
[1]   iat: 16138989,
[1]   exp: 16164909
[1] }
```

En el siguiente console.log(payload._id), ya me dice que esta undefined. Es aquí donde esta perdiendo toda la tada, justo despues del console.log anterior.

Os dejo mi configuracion de la interface IPayload

```
export interface IPayload {
    _id: string;
    iat: number;
    exp: number;
}
```

Y tambien esta configurado todo para que Typescript me de como valido el userId al ser requerido.

Muchas gracias a todos, si falta algo mas por subir, diganme.

Aquí dejo el codigo de como estoy generando el token

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import User, { IUser } from '../models/User';

import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

export const singIn = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

    const { email, password } = req.body;

    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });

        if(!user) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                msg: 'Email incorrecto'
            });
        };

        if(!bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                msg: 'Contraseña incorrecta'
            });
        };

        const token: string = jwt.sign({ 
            _id: user._id
        }, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET || 'secret_token', { 
            expiresIn: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
        });
        
        return res.header('auth-token', token).json(user);

    } catch(error) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            message: 'Ocurrió un error',
            error
        });
    };
};
```

Comment: Porque estás accediendo a un campo que no existe: `payload._id`. Cuando en realidad deseas acceder a `payload.data._id`. Verifica eso y comenta el resultado. Saludos

Comment: Habia intentado realizar eso mismo, pero TypeScript me da un error. Me dice que data no existe y consiguiente, _id tampoco. Le añadí data al interface de Payload y también se lo añadi como otro request mas a TypeScript, pero sigue dando error en el data que me comentas. Gracias y un saludo

Comment: debe ser header "auth-token" o "Authorization"  ?

Comment: Debe ser de la misma forma que lo hayas llamado a la hora de generarlo. En este caso auth-token. En este caso, ese no es el problema, ya que el token se genera correctamente y lo recibo bien tambien. Tengo el problema a la hora de acceder a la data

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir cómo estás generando ese Token?

Comment: Por supuesto amigo.   Lo dejo en el codigo de arriba, gracias.